# Why does values for sum(balance) change? How to fix/join the two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am having trouble understanding why my query changes the values of the sum of balance... and then I am unable to join the table back that I originally need.

Initial code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state = 'AZ' THEN 'AZ' ELSE 'Non-AZ' END AS state
     , COUNT(DISTINCT m.member_id) AS "No of Members"
     , COUNT(issue_detail_id) AS "Num Checkouts"
     , COUNT(DISTINCT li.lib_item_id) AS "Items Borrowed"
     , SUM(balance)
  FROM lib2.members m
  JOIN lib2.issue_details id ON m.member_id = id.member_id
  JOIN lib2.library_item_copies lic ON id.item_copy_id = lic.item_copy_id
  JOIN lib2.library_items li ON lic.lib_item_id = li.lib_item_id
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN state = 'AZ' THEN 'AZ' ELSE 'Non-AZ' END;
```

```
    AZ  7   37  18  -165
Non-AZ  6   30  14  -160
```

But when I do the separate query I get the intended results...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state = 'AZ' THEN 'AZ' ELSE 'Non-AZ' END AS "State"
     , COUNT(DISTINCT m.member_id) AS "No of Members"
     , SUM(balance) AS bal
  FROM lib2.members m
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN state = 'AZ' THEN 'AZ' ELSE 'Non-AZ' END;
```

```
Non-AZ  6   -35
    AZ  7   -30
```

Answer (score 1):

The "`sum(balance)`" will sum the balance of every row returned by the query.

When you do the query separately (second case), each row in the `lib2.members` table is processed just once.

When you add all the `JOIN` with the other tables, if there are for example multiple `lib2.issue_details` for a particular member, that member's row will be processed more than once, so the "`sum(balance)`" will not be correct.

Comment: How would I join the 2nd query then to make it grad those values rather than the balance from the first query?

Answer (score 0):

A `JOIN` by default is an inner join. So, Oracle will only keep rows where all the joins are true. If the `issue_details` table doesn't contain certain `member_id`, it will not count those rows.
What you want to use is a `LEFT JOIN`. That should probably be the issue, assuming you code is semantically fine and the join conditions are correct.

Comment: LEFT join still causes same result, the issue is a cartesian product because every time a member showed up for the issue_details the balance was carried and added into sum rather than sum being separate..